# Can we use Flex 3.0 for ASP 2.0

Tags: apache-flex, asp-classic, flex3

I am a Java developer with knowledge and experience in classic ASP 2.0.

In our organization we have couple of products in Classic ASP 2.0 built some 6 years ago.
We want to have new functions & modules built in Flex 3.0 (making use of rich UI) with in the existing classic ASP 2.0 Application. such that we dont reenginre the entire existing product into Flex.

SO my basic query is can we use Flex 3.0 in ASP 2.0, if so how. What plugins do we need to make it work, any document with example would be utmost help.

Thanks & Regards,
Sai Kirshna.

Answer (score 1):

You could check Adobe: http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Flex+and+ASP.NET

If you treat ASP as the server-side and Flex as the client-side, then you just need to sort out what the api will be. Flex has a number of ways to get data from the server. I use HTTP to get JSON data from the server.

If you want to still use the client-pieces of ASP, then you probably want to pass data around using the flash ExternalInterface. This allows you to pass data back and forth between the browser JavaScript and the Flash Object.

You're short on details, so you'll have to do some reading, but I've outlined the two basic strategies available (fetch data from server, fetch data from client). No plugins necessary so far.

---

EDIT: Here's some additional links to see if they help:

[Flexcontainer project](http://code.google.com/p/flexcontainer/) -- "Bi-directional messaging between ASP.NET and Flex is fully supported". I never tried this. It just came up in a search.

[ExternalInterface example](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html#exampleas3). This is your best bet. This is the communication between Flex and the browser I mentioned earlier. I don't have any simple code examples for you.

Comment: Hi Glenn,

Thanks for a precised information on the solution approach.

I would get data from server using ASP existing application framework which we built.
 Then I need to pass on these details to flex UI for rendering and client side validations, on return data should be sent back to ASp for business logic processing.

so can you please tell me how to shate data between ASP & flex uI fro, how to fetch data processed by ASp page from flex UI.

any Code example or doco would be quite promissing & helpful.

Thanks 7 Regards,
Sai

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not exactly get you back to classic ASP 2.0 but there is a .Net flavor of WebOrb which can be used to connect Flex to a .Net back-end might be helpful enough.

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html